# Get remote files by a list preserving their relative paths, and do it on a remote machine

Tags: ssh, sftp, file-server, lftp

1) I run SSH session on the remote client to get files from the server.

2) There is a server and it keeps a very broad directory structure.

3) I've got a list of thousands path-names to the files on the server. Yet they are only a small fracture of the whole content of the server. So, the files are to be fetched one-by-one, not by directories, no wild cards.

Task: get all files **by the list** and place them on the client machine with all the **relative paths created on the client**.

The problem I've encountered is that the sftp cannot write a file in the non-existed dir:

```
get -p /q/w/e/r/t/y/file /base/q/w/e/r/t/y/file
```

does not create all the sequence of q/w/e/r/t/y/ in the /base/ (not even the 1-st subdirectory)

Note: the solution may be for a single file too. I'll try to make batch after it.

Not important note: actually, I don't need those paths - but there may be files with the same names and they should not conflict on the new place. So the idea of draining all files in one plain directory is not acceptable.

Comment: If you have `rsync` on both sides you can use that with a file list. (It runs over `ssh`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a combination of mkdir and dirname  before you do a sftp

```
mkdir -p $(dirname /base/q/w/e/r/t/y/file)
```

- `dirname` will extract the full directory path to the file
- `mkdir -p` will ensure that the entire directory tree is created
  (even if it is partially available)

Comment: thanks! The problem is, sftp command `lmdkir` has no flag -p. So, I cannot enter sftp and perform creation of the dir and getting the file. As I see it, the separated script should be launched to create the directory tree and then the sftp session - to get files. BTW, lftp does have the `mkdir -p` - but I have no rights to install lftp on the client machine...

Comment: You can use `!mkdir`. See [`!` "command"`](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp#!)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, thanks for this new hint! So far I've made the 2-phase procedure: one script processes all the list and creates the dir tree, the next script is sftp get. But it's just because of the time limit. I'll return to your suggestion later. Thank you!